# How to convert SQL table data into a dictionary

Tags: python, sql, dictionary

I have SQL data from a table in the form (songID, title, artist)
Example:

```
(0, 'Fix You', 'Coldplay')
(1, 'How to Save a Life', 'The Fray')
(2, 'Chasing Cars', 'Snow Patrol')
(3, 'Colide', 'Howie Day')
```

My task is to format this data into a dictionary called songs so it appears:

```
songs = {songID: [title, artist], songID: [title, artist], ...}
```

*the database is just called database*

Answer (score 2):

If you have data like this:

```
data = [(0, 'Fix You', 'Coldplay'),
        (1, 'How to Save a Life', 'The Fray'),
        (2, 'Chasing Cars', 'Snow Patrol'),
        (3, 'Colide', 'Howie Day')]
```

You could convert it to dict as following:

```
>>> {id: [title, artist] for id, title, artist in data} 
{0: ['Fix You', 'Coldplay'],
 1: ['How to Save a Life', 'The Fray'],
 2: ['Chasing Cars', 'Snow Patrol'],
 3: ['Colide', 'Howie Day']}
```